# Virtual machine with two virtual disks to docker container

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I've a virtual machine with two virtual disks (vmdk format):

- disk1 mounts in /
- disk2 mounts in /foo

I've converted these two disks to raw format, copied its content to a .tgz file and imported to Docker:

- disk1.vmkdk => disk1.raw => disk1.tgz => import image1
- disk2.vmkdk => disk2.raw => disk2.tgz => import image2

If run the image1 everything seems ok with the obvious fact that content of disk2 is not available.

How can I create a container that uses the content of both disks with the same path structure than the initial virtual machine?